# How to interact with Tree in XUL window?

Tags: firefox-addon, xul, firefox-addon-sdk

I need something to interact with Tree control on XUL form. How to do this?

I have main XUL window with Three(something contains), by clicking on the button I show the dialog(adding new tree item).

Need know, what is the selected item of tree and got some info from it, and send this info  to the dialog form.

How to from this dialog, get Tree from parent Window?

Comment: Did you read, the MDN articles? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/search?q=xul%20tree

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the dialog code, you can use `window.opener` to refer to parent window.